# Install CDT Plug-In On Eclipse Ganymede

Tags: c++, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

How i can install the CDT plug-in (that you can develop in C++ under Eclipse) in my Eclipse Ganymede, remember that I use Windows Vista. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good question, i can't find the result searching in Google, only for installation under Callisto version. Thanks!

Comment: It's tacky to favorite your own questions.

Comment: But you don't have to down vote because of this!!!!!!

Comment: Another aspect might be that you are asking multiple questions per hour, which is generally frowned upon.

Comment: I only want to get some knowlead.

Comment: I'm not the one downvoting your question, so don't ask me the motive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this official guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_started_with_CDT_development

Comment: This guide seems to be for contributing to CDT and not developing with CDT.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Are_there_complete_HowTos_for_setting_up_the_CDT.3F

Comment: It seems that most of the links this references are broken.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Pulse for this kind of stuff.  It manages all plugin dependencies and so far has worked very well for me